# Is $f$ finite a.e.?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(q_k)_{k\ge 1}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty]$ be defined as :

$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{k\ge 1}\frac{e^{-|x - q_k|}}{k^2 \sqrt{|x-q_k|}}$$

Is it true that $\lambda(\{x \ | \ |f(x)| < \infty\}) = 0$ ? ($\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.)

The only thing I can think of is the obvious one, i.e. $f(\mathbb{Q})= \{\infty\}$. But I'm completely lost for the case $x \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int f(x)dx =\sum \frac 1 {k^2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac {e^{-|x-q_k|}} {\sqrt {|x-q_k|}}dx$ by an application of Tonelli's Theorem. But  $\sup_k \int_0^{\infty} \frac {e^{-|x-q_k|}} {\sqrt {|x-q_k|}}dx=\sup_k\int_{-q_k}^{\infty} \frac {e^{-|y|}} {\sqrt {|y|}}dx\leq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {e^{-|y|}} {\sqrt {|y|}}dx<\infty$. This proves that $\int f(x)dx <\infty$ and hence, $f(x) <\infty$ a.e..

Comment: You need $e^{-|y|}$ under the integral and perhaps mention that those integrals are uniformly bounded with respect to $k$. ($2\sqrt{\pi}$ is an upper bound)

Comment: @Gary Thanks for the corrections. I have edited my answer.